# Proof for $n<m$ iff $n\leq m$ and $n\ne m$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It's a basic exrecise on Set Theory course.

We constructed the natural numbers by $0=\emptyset$ and $n+1=n\cup \{n\}$.

So basically the order relation defined by $m<n$ if $m\in n$, and $m\leq n$ if $m\subseteq n$.

We need to prove (by induction? I guess..) that:

$n\in m$ iff $n\subseteq m$ and $n\ne m$

I don't see how to even begin. please, help.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try.

For $m=\emptyset$, if $n\in \emptyset$ then (everything follows...) $n\subseteq \emptyset$ and $n\ne m$.

If $n\subseteq \emptyset$ then $n=\emptyset$ therefore the other direction is also "empty"..

Assume that $n\in m \Leftrightarrow n\subseteq m$ and $n\ne m$

Now, if $n\in m+1$ iff $n\in m\cup \{m\}$, iff $n\in m$ or $n=m$.

If $n\in m$ then (induction hypothesis ..) $n\subseteq m$ and $n\ne m$.
since $m\subseteq m+1$ it follows that $n\subseteq m+1$, and obviously $n\ne m+1$, since if $n=m+1$, then $m+1\subseteq m$ which means that $m+1=m$ which is a contradiction.

Therefore $n\in m+1 \Rightarrow n\subseteq m+1$ and $n\ne m+1$.

On the other direction, if $n\subseteq m+1$ and $n\ne m+1$, then $n\subseteq m\cup \{m\}$.

If $m\in n$ then $n=m+1$ (Not sure how to explain why ..) which is a contradiction. Therefore $n\subseteq m$, and then $n\in m$ (induction hypo..) and since $m\subseteq m+1$ it follows that $n\in m+1$.